# Estimating value of $h$ needed to cap the approximation error of $\ln{(1+h)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

We know that

$$\ln{(1+h)} = h - \frac{h^2}{2} +...$$

What is the method for finding how much we should cap $h$ at, to cap the approximation error of $\ln{(1+h)}=h$ at a certain value, like $10^{-3}$ or something like this? I want to solve this using Taylor remainder theorem.

Comment: Apply Taylor's remainder theorem.

Comment: Assuming $h\in(-1,1)$, we may notice that

$$ E(h)=\log(1+h)-h+\frac{h^2}{2}=\int_{0}^{h}\frac{1}{1+x}-(1-x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{h}x^2\frac{dx}{1+x} $$
is at most $\frac{1}{3}|h|^3$ and assuming $h>0$ it is better bounded by
$$ \sqrt{\int_{0}^{h}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}\,dx \int_{0}^{h}x^2\,dx}=\sqrt{\frac{h^3}{3}\left(\frac{h(2+h)}{1+h}-2\log(1+h)\right)} $$
due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$ E(h) \leq \sqrt{\frac{h^3}{3}\left(\frac{h^3}{1+h}-2E(h)\right)}\quad \to \quad E(h)\leq\frac{h^3}{(h+1)+\sqrt{h^2+5h+4}}\leq\frac{h^3}{3+2h}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you approximate $\ln(1+h)$ to $h$, then Taylor's remainder theorem yields that there exists $t\in(0,h)$ such that $\ln(1+h)=h-\dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}\dfrac{h^2}{2}$. Then the error $\left\lvert\ln(1+h)-h\right\rvert\le\dfrac{h^2}{2}$, since $\dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}$ is decreasing. If you want to cap the approximation error at $10^{-3}$, then $\dfrac{h^2}{2}\le 10^{-3}$, and you can do the rest of the calculation.

Comment: Taylor's theorem yields:
$$\ln(1+h)=h-\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\frac{h^2}{2} $$
for some $t\in(0,h)$. Which remainder form are you using?

Comment: @bjorn93 I've edited it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatives to Taylor's Remainder Theorem**

We can use
$$
\frac{h}{1+h}\le\overbrace{\int_0^h\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}}^{\log(1+h)}\le h
$$
we get the maximum error is
$$
\left|\,\log(1+h)-h\,\right|\le\frac{h^2}{1+h}
$$

---

However, if $h\ge0$, we can use Jensen's inequality and the convex function $\frac1{1+x}$ to get
$$
\frac1h\int_0^h\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x}\ge\frac1{1+\frac1h\int_0^hx\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac1{1+\frac12h}
$$
which gives a better bound of
$$
\left|\,\log(1+h)-h\,\right|\le\frac{h^2}{2+h}
$$